# Assign values from list to dictionary without for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I need the same output by not using any loops.

I have two lists:

```
groupVal = ["Staff 1","Staff 2"]
nameValue = ["ABC","XYZ"]
```

My code looks like this:

```
sdict = {"group": {}}
for index, item in enumerate(groupVal):
    sdict ['group'][item] = {"name": "Hi "+nameValue[index], "approval" :"yes"}
```

Output for sdict:

```
{'group': {'Staff 1': {'name': 'Hi ABC', "approval" :"yes"}, 'Staff 2': {'name': 'Hi XYZ', "approval" :"yes"}}}
```

Comment: Its not possible to iterate over lists to create your output without any loop

Comment: I think OP just means (s)he needs some kind of comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, a one liner for the whole `sdict`

```py
groupVal = ["Staff 1","Staff 2"]
nameValue = ["ABC","XYZ"]

sdict = {'group': {item: {'name': 'Hi ' + value, 'approval': 'yes'} for item, value in zip(groupVal, nameValue)}}

sdict
{'group': {
    'Staff 1': {'name': 'Hi ABC', 'approval': 'yes'},
    'Staff 2': {'name': 'Hi XYZ', 'approval': 'yes'}
  }
}
```

Comment: `map` can be used here?

Comment: Yes, just rewrite the generated item part of for loop in lambda.

Comment: Can you give an example? @Brandon

Comment: @SoumeeGiri `sdict = {'group': dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], {'name': 'Hi '+x[1], 'approval': 'yes'}), zip(groupVal, nameValue)))}` Hope this will help ;)